# stoping a running timer with a random user input

Tags: c#

I am currently experimenting with Timers.
I made a timer that counts down 5 seconds and the closes the programm.

However, I don't seem to figure out how to interupt and stop the timer from closing the programm when pressing a random key.

But I am missing a function like Timer.Stop()

```
    private static void CommandExit()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Thank you for your input!");
        Console.WriteLine("The programm will now close. \r\n");
        var countdown = 5;
        var myTimer = new Timer(state =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Program is closing in: '{0}' ", countdown);
            countdown--;
             if (countdown <= 0)
            {
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
            if (countdown != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Press any Key to interrupt the closing process.");
                var breakuptoken = Console.ReadKey();
                if (breakuptoken != null)
                {
                //SOMETHING IS MISSING HERE
                }
            }
        }, null,0, 1000);

    }
```

Solution:

```
private static void CommandExit()
    {
        var countdown = 5;
        Console.WriteLine("Thank you for your input!");
        Console.WriteLine("The programm will now close. \r\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Press any Key to interrupt the closing process.");
        var myTimer = new Timer(state =>
        {
        Console.WriteLine("Program is closing in: '{0}' ", countdown);
            countdown--;
        if (countdown <= 0)
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }

        }, null, 0, 1000);
        Console.ReadKey();
        myTimer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);          
    }
```

Comment: You have a (blocking) ReadKey in your timer handler. That is just plain wrong.  You can try to fix it with Console.KeyAvaialble but frankly, Console apps are not meant for this kind of interactivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the type of timer you are using:

System.Windows.Forms.Timer: `timer.Enabled = false;`
System.Threading.Timer: `timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);`
System.Timers.Timer: `timer.Enabled = false;` or `timer.Stop();`

Solution specific to your use-case:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CommandExit();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

        private static void CommandExit()
    {
        var countdown = 5;
        Console.WriteLine("Thank you for your input!");
        Console.WriteLine("The programm will now close. \r\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Press any Key to interrupt the closing process.");
        var myTimer = new Timer(state =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Program is closing in: '{0}' ", countdown);
            countdown--;
            if (countdown <= 0)
            {
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        }, null, 0, 1000);
        Console.ReadKey();
        myTimer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);          
    }
}
```

Comment: Edit: Since i am under 50 reputation i can't comment on the answer @Noah shared.
Make sure you use one of these functions under the constructor of `var myTimer`

Comment: Are you still getting the "Cannot use local variable 'myTimer' before it is declared" error?

Comment: The problem is that none of the 3 functions work for me :(

Comment: Try changing it to `this.Stop`
Also, can you tell me what kind of Timer you are using? It is shown at the top of your class file: `using xx.xx.Timer`

Comment: Using System.Timers;

Comment: I made a mockup for a template which should work.
Since i dont know the extent of your application, this should be interpreted instead of copied.
It is shown in my edited answer

Comment: I guess you are some kind of wizard! that worked! Thanks a lot :) I think i just accepted it.

Comment: Since learning to code is all about understanding what is happening, allow me to explain what i changed:
`Console.ReadLine();` keeps the console window open after the `RunTimer()` is finished, so it doesnt look like it closed anyway.
Moving `myTimer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);` out of the constructor made the compiler understand that `myTimer` is a variable, and execute functions on it.

Comment: I see! I modified the Code a bit by removing a lot of the ifs. Makes it easier to read! I edit the OP!